# Form inputs to class properties

Tags: php, forms, class, oop, constructor

I'm trying to learn OO PHP and I'm working on a contents manager project, I want to construct an object starting from an html form.

For example, if I have a form with ten textbox (or other types of input), I sent the form in POST mode, then I want to construct my object starting from POST data.

Do I have to pass them as constructor's parameters, or as an array? How?

Just an example:

My little form: Name, Surname, Description (but there might be over ten inputs)

My $_POST array: ('name'=>'Mario', 'surname'=>'Rossi', 'description'=>'Just a description here.')

My class:

```
class Person {
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $description;

    public function __contruct(/*arguments or array here*/) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean and easy solution is to use the `json_decode` and `json_encode` functions.

http://php.net/json_decode

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($_POST['formdata']), FALSE);
```

`json_decode` converts your formdata to an serialized object and the second parameter of `json_encode` (false) prevents the data from being converted back to an `array`.

Comment: What benefit does this have over casting as an object? http://codepad.org/d5OsitKp - no difference in output, yet the json functions are slower.

Comment: No, it works recursive. Just casting to object only converts the first level to an object. json_encode/decode works for subarrays as well.

Comment: On associative arrays yes, but there is no mention from the asker that this is what they want. The question was only to convert `$_POST` to an object, not it's children.

Comment: Associative: definitely, because the data comes from an html form. Multidimensional: probably, think of `name="id[]" value="1"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly use `$_POST` in the function rather send it as parameter to the function

Function call from CLASS object:

```
$args = array(
   'val1' => $_POST['val1'],
   'val2' => $_POST['val2'],
   'val3' => $_POST['val3']
);
$obj->funct($args);
```

Function definition in CLASS:

```
public function funct ($param = array()) {
   print_r( $param );
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `public function funct () { print_r($_POST); }`

Comment: just a suggestion, nothing is wrong with using `$_POST`. But It will be easy for the changes in future if you send them as an argument..

Comment: @TheEscapist edit your question and add that, it's too difficult to read as a comment..

Comment: @zzlalani ok but if I have many inputs it's insane sending them all as arguments of conscructor. I might send them as array, but if I send $_POST directly there might be other external elements, if I send the right array I should create it from $_POST, using other lines of code.

What's the better solution?

Comment: @zzlalani ok, so I have to create my array and pass it as argument.

Answer (score 0):

If your form has data beyond one `Person`, then one `Person` is not enough to represent your form!

Have a class `PersonForm` (or whatever name it may be), and pass in the `$_POST` array as an argument.

The `PersonForm` can then create (either by `new` or by using a `PersonFactory` class) the `Person` objects using some of the data from the array.